# Find successive maximum differences in array

Tags: ios

I have created an application in which the user continually rotates the phone about the z-axis (yaw) with the screen of the phone facing upwards.  I would like to generate the angle between the two extremes each time the rotation changes direction.

Imagine an array of the following values: [-5,-3,-2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2,-1,-3,-4,-7,-4,-3,...].  What I would like to do is find the relative maximums and minimums of the array in order to find the differences from one relative minimum to the next relative maximum.  In the given array, -5 would be the first relative minimum and then 6 would be the next relative maximum.  The difference here would be 11 units.  From that relative maximum of 6, the next relative minimum is -7.  The difference here would be 13 units.  The process would continue on until the end of the array.  I would like these difference values to be entered into an array of their own, i.e. [11,13,...].  Would greatly appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Not really an iOS issue, as the problem is both device and language independent; and certainly has nothing to do with Xcode.  There are also a ton of solutions to this problem that are all equally valid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see this your first value in the array is always your initial relative minimum AND maximum since you have absolutely no basis of comparison from the get-go (unless you prime both relMin and relMax to 0 OR define a range to find your relMin and relMax). With that in mind the logic behind your example itself is flawed given your assumption of using -5 & 6 as the first comparison pair.

Let's use your array and iterate through the array with a For Loop...

```
[-5,-3,-2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2,-1,-3,-4,-7,-4,-3,...]
```

> 0: relMin = -5, relMax = -5, delta = 0
>
> 1: relMin = -5, relMax = -3, delta = 2
>
> 2: relMin = -5, relMax = -2, delta = 3
>
> 3: relMin = -5, relMax = 0, delta = 5
>
> 4: relMin = -5, relMax = 1, delta = 6
>
> 5: relMin = -5, relMax = 2, delta = 2
>
> 6: relMin = -5, relMax = 6, delta = 11
>
> 7:
>
> ....
>
> 13: relMin = -7, relMax = 6, delta = 13
>
> ....

Essentially what you're doing is writing to your output array any time your current delta is not equal to your previous delta. Since a change between relMin and relMax is mutually exclusive (only one of those values can change as you traverse the array) all you have to check for is inequality...

```
//prime your values
//if it make sense for your purposes prime them both with 0
//this also assumes you have at least 1 value in valueArray
relMin = valueArray[0];
relMax = valueArray[0];

//the following line will always be true if you use valueArray[0] as your relMin and relMax baseline
deltaArray[0] = 0;
for (i = 0; i < [valueArray count]; i++)
{
 if (valueArray[i] < relMin)
 {
  relMin = valueArray[i];
 }
 if (valueArray[i] > relMax)
 {
  relMax = valueArray[i];
 }
 deltaPrevious = deltaArray[[deltaArray count] - 1];
 deltaCurrent = relMax - relMin;
 if (deltaCurrent != deltaPrevious)
 {
  deltaArray[deltaArray count] = deltaCurrent;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would be to first write an algorithm that detects the indices of the maximums and minimums, and then finds differences from there.

To get the maxes and mins, I would recommend iterating through the array and looking at the difference between the current and the previous and next value.  You need to looking at changes in sign of the differences:
A **minimum** will occur when the differences change from negative to positive, and a **maximum** will occur when the differences change from positive to negative.

For example, look at this part of your array: [1,2,6,5,3].  The difference from 1 to 2 is positive, from 2 to 6 is positive, but from 6 to 5 is negative.  The sign of the differences changed from positive to negative at the 6, so we know it is a maximum.

Note that you also need to include the first and last elements as possible maxes or mins.

Once you get the indices of maximums and minimums, you should be able to get their differences fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

In a most basic sense, you could iterate through the array, checking to see if the next value is greater than or less than the previous value.  Whenever you reach a change (was increasing, now decreasing, or vice versa) you have found a relative max/min (respectively).  A for loop to iterate, a boolean flag to check against (whether you were increasing or decreasing) and the obvious knowledge of both your current and previous index in the array to check/store.

I don't quite feel comfortable giving exact code for this since it's very basic and seems very much like a homework question...